# Jenkins unable to find npm

Tags: node.js, linux, jenkins, npm

On this linux server, I have a user named "myuser".
For this user, when echoing the path, I get this:

/home/myuser/bin:/home/myuser/.local/bin:/home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Having a node application, when deploying manually I run:

```
npm i
```

And it works.

Now, I installed Jenkins. Jenkins project I'm trying to install is located at:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test
```

The build is executing a shell script. In that window I entered:

```
#!/bin/bash
npm i
```

When building with Jenkins, I get this:

```
[test] $ /bin/bash /tmp/jenkins756533162549346948.sh
/tmp/jenkins756533162549346948.sh: line 3: npm: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

If I only write:

```
echo $PATH
```

in the Jenkins shell, I get this:

```
[test] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins5067097808572366507.sh
+ echo /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin
[test] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/6.11.1/bin/node /tmp/jenkins8733250738704177758.js
Finished: SUCCESS
```

As you can see, I installed nodejs plugin.
Anyway, when using Jenkins shell, the npm and even node are not found. 
How can I make Jenkins to know where npm/node is?
I have tried to first write this in the shell:

$PATH=/home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/bin

But still no luck.

Comment: Jenkins launches a new shell...

Comment: So you might want to source the update the PATh within the jenkins script itself..

Comment: Yes, I updated the path within the jenkins shell itself, but still no luck.

Comment: I used [this tutorial](https://plugins.jenkins.io/nodejs/) (just the beggining)

Answer (score 27):

I have been battling with this for some time now. Finally found the solution. From your jobs menu select `Configure` under `Build Environment` select `Provide Node & npm bin/ folder to PATH` You can leave the default setting and you are good to go.

[image]

As specified by Eric Wang in the comments, the `NodeJS Plugin` needs to be installed first for this option to come up:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin

Comment: Seems need to install `node plugin` first, to get this option.

Comment: after installation of node plugin and providing build environment worked. thanks

Comment: I installed NodeJS Plugin and I don't have a Build Environment section, do I need something else to see that?

Comment: @ocramot were you able to find a workaround?

Comment: @user805981 I used DenLilleMand's solution below.

Comment: I can confirm this worked for me. thanks a lot @tutug

Comment: I also confirm that this worked for me

Comment: @ocramot There is a Build Environment configuration in every Jenkins job configuration. Go to URL <yourjenkinsroot>/job/<yourjob>/configure and you will find it on the left in the main menu.

Answer (score 19):

The answers in this thread didn't help me, what helped was adding the node.js tool to my Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  tools {nodejs "nodejs"}

  stages {
    stage('Example') {
      steps {
        sh 'npm config ls'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Where the string `"nodejs"` is the `name` you give the node.js tool in the `global tool configuration`

Comment: how to use it in scripted pipeline script
using it like this:```
    env.GRADLE_USER_HOME = "${env.WORKSPACE}/.gradle"
    def nodejsTool = 'NodeJS-14.20.0' //
    env.JAVA_HOME="${tool 'jdk-1.8.0_321'}"
    env.PATH="${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin:${env.PATH}:${tool nodejsTool}"
    ```
give me error: script.sh: line 1: node: command not found

Answer (score 12):

Just install the `nodeJS plugin` for jenkins, you can find it [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin).

After installing the plugin, restart jenkins, and go to the global configs to specify the version.

The full details of configurations can be found in the plugin documentation linked above.

---

### Update for jenkins 2.x

To get to the plugin page in jenkins 2.x:

> simply go to `Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins` view, available to administrators of a Jenkins environment. - https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/plugins/

However, I do recommend using [pipelines](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/) instead of a plugin for the CI process:

Pipelines are instructions to **describe portions of your software delivery pipeline**.

Add this pipeline config to your node.js project on jenkins to have it running.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'node:6-alpine'
            args '-p 3000:3000'
        }
    }
    environment {
        CI = 'true' 
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm install'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') { 
            steps {
                sh './jenkins/scripts/test.sh' 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see this runs two stages, *building* and *testing* for the application. `npm` is installed through the docker image `node:6-alpine`.

Jenkins docs provide a full tutorial to build a nodejs app through CI: https://jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-node-js-and-react-app-with-npm/

Comment: Ok what I was missing was to check this checkbox: "Provide Node & npm bin/ folder to PATH". When I did this, the shell executed without errors.

Comment: I was having the same issue, this checkbox also solved my issue!

Comment: @Theo, On the "Build environnment" section of job configuration. See https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin

Comment: i don't see any build environment section on my job config. do I need to install any plugin for this to appear? @sasha_trn?

Comment: i'm using jenkins version 2.131 btw

Answer (score 6):

If you are using pipelines.

1. Install the NodeJS Jenkins plugin
2. Configure Node installation in the Global Tool Configurations
   [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRTTv.png)
3. Whenever you want to use npm in your pipeline use:

   ```
   nodejs('<name of your Node installation>'){

      //here your npm commands p.e.

      npm install
      npm run prod
   }
   ```

Answer (score 5):

At first, go to **Manage Jenkins**/**Global Tool Configuration**, configure nodejs installer like below.

[image]

Now go to Jenkinsfile and include the above tool.

```
tools {nodejs "NODEJS"}  //name should be similar to name used for installer in the global tool configuration.
```

This worked for me.

Comment: This option is not under "Global tool config"... where is it?

Comment: @Petro you have to click on "Add NodeJS" under https://your-jenkins-url/manage/configureTools/

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that worked for me in a pipeline scenario is adding the

> tools {nodejs "Your Node JS Installation Name"}

After you install the Node JS plugin and add a new configuration in the **Manage Jenkins->Global Tool Configuration** menu.

Answer (score 1):

After installing NodeJS restart you PC , npm will be visible to Jenkins

Comment: Patially this helped me to solve the issue, I just restarted the Jenkis then it started working without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

used nvm to install Node.js

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.0/install.sh | bash

. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

nvm install 4.4.5

node -v //4.4.5
```

Also,In jenkins, Manage Jenkins>>Global tool conf>> Nodejs installation

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```bash
n=$(which node);
n=${n%/bin/node};
chmod -R 755 $n/bin/*;
sudo cp -r $n/{bin,lib,share} /usr/local
```

Answer (score -2):

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Install") {
            steps {
                sh "npm install"
            }
        }
        stage("Build") {
            steps {
                sh "npm run build"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to install 'npm' first to be able to run those commands in the example. The commands use the 'npm' on your workspace contents.