# NPM commands fails when executed as a Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, npm

I want to run a simple npm -v command via a Jenkins. It works perfectly well when running on backend as Jenkins user in the job's workspace directory.

But when a Jenkins job run it..this is the error message that it is showing in the console output.

/tmp/hudson4434208258557634970.sh: line 5: npm: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

The Jenkins job would clone a directory from Git and then executes a shell script with just npm -v command.

## !/bin/bash

npm -v

Why can't a Jenkins job run this command?

Comment: Are you sure npm is available on your path? Try using the binary directly, I assume it's for a link to it in /usr/bin. If that works it's likely either the binary is not available on the PATH for that user or the user doesn't have permissions to it.

Comment: Looks like this post might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45914038/jenkins-unable-to-find-npm